# Unterschied zwischen sorgen , kümmern , betreuen , pflegen

Tags: english-to-german, german-to-english, standard-german

Was ist der unterschied zwischen sorgen , kümmern , betreuen , pflegen??

Comment: Please provide a reason why a dictionary didn't help you or what's left unclear.

Comment: It is important to give some context in order to make sure you don't get the wrong answer (as I think is already the case) and get downvoted with few-to-no explanation (as is already the case). If that is what lead to your post, you could add that you looked for the translation of "to care" or "to care of" and you don't get the subtle difference between the four most relevant translations.

Comment: @infinitezero A dictionary will provide definitions, but it will not provide differences between words, right?!

Answer (score 3):

This depends on context mostly.

- *Sich sorgen* means *to be full of sorrows*, and *für jemanden/etwas sorgen* is what you do to address those sorrows.
- *Kümmern* is the same, but from the opposite direction. *Bekümmern* is what someone or something does what makes you sad. *Kümmern* is what you do to address that problem.
- *Betreuen* means being the custodian to someone (its stem is *treu*!), e.g. kids on an excursion or legally for persons with mental illnesses. It's often used for general caregiving however.
- *Pflegen* means keeping something neat and tidy. You can *pflegen* your garden, your car or a relationship. Or simply persons.

Comment: Ich nehme an, dass der OP nach dem reflexiven "sich kümmern (um)" fragt, nicht nach dem viel selteneren nicht-reflexiven "kümmern".

Comment: Even though the question is (at the time of this comment) rather ill-formulated, I think it's pretty clear from the context that the OP looked up "to care (of)" in the dictionary and got those four words displayed. In this context, your first translation is wrong. Think of it as in "Die Nachbarin sorgt für die Katze in meiner Abwesenheit“. It's really about "sorgen" and not "sich sorgen".

Comment: It's pretty clear from my explantion I use the reflexive variant mainly as a mnemonic.

Comment: So wie die Frage gestellt ist, sind alle syntaktischen Kombinationen angesprochen, für _kümmern_ also _sich um jn/etw kümmern, sich kümmern, etw kümmert jn (nicht)_, entsprechend für die anderen Verben. Für die Bedeutung  gibt es jeweils bei dict.cc (u.a.) gute Übersetzungsvorschläge auf Englisch. Typische Objekte, Subjekte und andere Ergänzungen findet man hier: https://www.dwds.de/wp/k%C3%BCmmern , wobei aber leider nicht nach reflexivem und nicht reflexivem Gebrauch und auch nicht nach anderen Bedeutungen (_die Pflanze kümmert vor sich hin_) unterschieden wird.